# Detect multiple collision point

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

How to detect multiple collision point in sprite body. I know the detection of sprite bodies but don't know in custom collision.

In my game i have player and enemy sprite both are in dynamic body and I want to detect collision in two way like mario type. Collision detection in top of the enemy and another is collision detection in front of enemy..

How can i do this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add different fixtures to the head and to the bottom of your enemy. then just check which enemy fixture collided with your hero

Comment: Okay but how can i add different fixture in one body as u say in head??

Comment: you can add any number of fuxtures to b2Body object. of course, in case of using Box2D to detect collisions

Comment: Okay but can you give me code or tutorial regarding this condition?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls